# SQL Server - Convert columns to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table on which simple select gives out put like below

[image]

I want to write a select statement to output like below

[image]

Can someone help me...

Comment: Sounds like you want to pivot.

Comment: Search for pivot and sql.

Comment: How are you planning on _displaying_ the data? Pivoting like this is typically much easier to do in reports and apps than in SQL.

Comment: Possible dupe:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091330/sql-server-convert-columns-to-rows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are basically rotating your current columns of `Sale`, `Income` and `Profit` into rows and then move the `month` values to columns, then you will want to first unpivot the current columns, then pivot the months.

Depending on your version of SQL Server there are a few ways that you can unpivot the data. You can use the UNPIVOT function or CROSS APPLY:

```
select month, type, value
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select 'Sale', sale union all
  select 'Income', Income union all
  select 'Profit', Profit
) c (type, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b7e0/2). This will convert your current data into:

```
| MONTH |   TYPE | VALUE |
|-------|--------|-------|
|   Jan |   Sale |   100 |
|   Jan | Income |    50 |
|   Jan | Profit |    10 |
|   Feb |   Sale |    20 |
|   Feb | Income |    40 |
```

Then you can use the PIVOT function to convert the months into your column headers.

```
select type, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr
from
(
  select month, type, value
  from yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Sale', sale union all
    select 'Income', Income union all
    select 'Profit', Profit
  ) c (type, value)
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for month in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b7e0/3).

if you have an unknown number of months, then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct N',' + QUOTENAME(Month) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT type, ' + @cols + N' 
            from 
            (
                select month, type, value
                from yourtable
                cross apply
                (
                  select ''Sale'', sale union all
                  select ''Income'', Income union all
                  select ''Profit'', Profit
                ) c (type, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(value)
                for month in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b7e0/6)

Comment: Solution looks good. Thank you bluefeet. But list of months is not known while writing the query, its dynamic. It may go up to December also. So today when I am running its till April, tomorrow it might be upto June. Any idea how to solve?

Comment: @KrishnarajBarvathaya See my edit, you will have to use dynamic sql.  Is your month value actually a string - jan, feb, etc?  Or it is stored as a date?  You will have to do some adjustments to the code if it is stored as either but the above should get you started.

Comment: Is there any other direct way to convert rows to column and vise versa? Because whatever "yourtable" is not a simple table. Its a complex query with lot of conditions. Also I don't have the luxury to define separate variable and multiple statements. I should be able to convert columns to rows in a single statement.

Comment: @KrishnarajBarvathaya If you are going to have an unknown number of columns, then you have to use dynamic sql.  It creates a sql string with all of the column name that will be executed, there is no easy way to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use UNPIVOT then PIVOT
THE BEST IS TO DO QUERY EMBEDED SQL
create DISTINCT COLUMS of months with STUFF function then
replace FOR oMonth IN ([January-2013], [February-2013], [March-2013], [April-2013])
  here core query

```
 SELECT  
*
FROM
(  SELECT      
 oMonth, value,col
 from (
 select DATENAME(month,oDate)   + '-' + CAST(YEAR(  oDate) as varchar) as oMonth,        Sales ,Income,Profit
 FROM            SalesSource 
 )A
unpivot
 (
  value for col in ( Sales ,Income,Profit)
 ) u

 ) as sourceTable
 PIVOT
 (
 sum( value)  
 FOR oMonth IN ([January-2013], [February-2013], [March-2013], [April-2013])
 ) AS PivotTable;
```